# Is the zk proof verifier program open source?

Tags: rust, token-2022, native-programs

So i wanted to get an idea on how the equality and range proofs get verified by the native proof verifier program but I don’t see verifier codebase anywhere. Is it open source? If not when will it be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the code is open-source! You can find the ZK SDKs at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/tree/master/zk-token-sdk, and I imagine you'll care most about the range proofs https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/tree/master/zk-token-sdk/src/range_proof and sigma proofs https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/tree/master/zk-token-sdk/src/sigma_proofs

Comment: So Sigma proofs are basically equality proofs right ?

Comment: Yep that's pretty much it. I forgot to link these docs, but they provide even more info: https://spl.solana.com/confidential-token/deep-dive/zkps#sigma-protocols

Comment: Btw can equality proofs be used to verify OTPs on-chain?